# Detect end of H264 video frame when RTP marker bit not present

Tags: video, h.264, rtp

RFC 3984 RTP Payload format Section 5.1 for H264 states regarding the RTP marker bit
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3984#page-34

"Decoders MAY use this bit as
an early indication of the last packet of an access unit, but MUST
NOT rely on this property."

In our iOS application we can send a complete video frame to the H264 HW decoder as soon as we detect the RTP marker bit set, however with some PBxs this bit is not set so we cannot detect the end of video frame this way.
Is it possible to determine the end of a video frame if the marker bit is not set by the sender?

Answer (score 0):

It decodes the frame. When the last macroblock is decoded, the next NALU belongs to the next AU.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to parse the bitstream to detect the last packet. At present I'm resigned to looking for the next packet with new timestamp

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Search stack overflow for finding the end of a frame. I’m sure I have seen it answered before.